# JavaScript RegExp that replaces _FOO_ with <code>FOO</code>

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string inside a variable:

```
var s = 'I have _this_ string inside a variable';
```

and I need a regular epxression which would produce this result:

```
'I have <code>this</code> string inside a variable'
```

Also, if the `_` character is a bad choice, I am willing to use any other character that is more suitable.

Also, if using the same character both as the left and right boundary is a bad idea, I am willing to use different charaters (like `\this/` or `>this<`).

---

I'd like the regex to execute only in this scenario:

One or more white-space characters,
followed by _,
followed by one ore more charaters that are not white-space or _,
followed by _,
followed by one or more white-space charaters.

So that:

`'foo _bar_ baz'` --> `'foo <code>bar</code> baz'`
`'foo _bar _ baz'` --> `'foo _bar _ baz'`
`'foo _b_ar_ baz'` --> `'foo _b_ar_ baz'`
`'foo _bar baz'` --> `'foo _bar baz'`

Comment: Without knowing more about what you are trying to do, it is hard to tell if it is a bad choice.  Simply consider that you may need an escape character, should you actually want to type `_this_` literally, and not have it replaced with `<code>this</code>`.

Comment: @Brad I am actually thinking of using the Croatian characters from my keyboard: ŠĐČĆŽšđčćž - because the text is in English, so there is no way that those characters will ever be used literally in the text. For instance `ŠthisŠ`

Comment: Here's a silly question - have you considered using `<code>` and `</code>`? seems more friendly than `☃code☃`

Comment: @Kobi You mean that I hard-code `<code>this</code>` in my source text? I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Sime, why?  You are hard coding the code that represents it anyway.

Comment: @Brad `_foo_` compared to `<code>foo</code>` is: 1. more readable (just compare the strings in my question - there is no doubt that it's easier to read the first one), 2. safer (less chance for a typo breaking the whole thing), 3. is not bound to a specific tag (I can choose to use <span> instead of <code> later on), 4. less redundant (I hate redundancy)

Answer (score 6):

Should be pretty simple:

```
s = s.replace(/_([^_]*)_/g, '<code>$1</code>');
```

The regex is straightforward:

- `(...)` - capturing group, so `$1` takes what's between the underscores
- `[^_]*` - some characters that are not underscores.

To the next question: It's hard to tell whether `_..._` is a good choice or not, it greatly depends on your typical data. For example, if `_` is common within your code you may have to escape it, which adds complexity.

---

The next one should fit your new rules:

```
s = s.replace(/(^|\s)_([^_\s]+)_(?!\S)/g, '<code>$1</code>');
```

This one is a little confusing. It should work according to your rules (though it also work near the start/end of the string, where you may not have a whitespace). Here's what we've got:

- `(^|\s)` - The first group is now the whitespcae, or the start of the line. JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind, so this will have to do.
- `_`
- `([^_\s]+)` - Main group - match characters that are not underscores or spaces.
- `_`
- `(?!\S)` - negative lookahead - check that the next character is not (not a space) - the double negative is there to make it work before the end of the string, it could have been `(?=\s|$)` if you are more comfortable with it.

An extra advantage of lookahead here is that it doesn't capture the last space. If you have two code words, for example `_hello_ _world_`, they will both be replaces. If we used `(\s|$)`, as with the space before the word, the first match would have consumed the space, and the second word could not have been matched.

Comment: +1 I'd agree that you'd want to make sure an uncommon character (or set of characters) is used. Throw an `_` in there between a couple of intended matched sets, and it throws it off.

Comment: @Kobi I've updated my question. Would you know how to enhance your regex so that it only executes in the scenario pointed out in my update?

Comment: I've edited but I'm nit quite there yet, missed all the rules. Anyway, I'm going out, it'd probably be solved by the time I come back. Good luck!

Comment: @Kobi Thanks, no problem :) I'm not in a hurry.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Ok, I was wrong, apparently no one else answered you yet. Here's another one, based on your rules.